# How to migrate old images saved by Paperclip to new styles and save it to s3 (and not saving the new files locally) ? (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, imagemagick, paperclip

I'm using Rails(4.0.1) with Paperclip (4.2.0) to save some images to S3.

I used to have a model PropertyImage:

```
class PropertyImage < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :picture,
    storage: :s3,
    s3_credentials: CONFIG['s3'],
    s3_protocol: (Rails.env.development? ? "http": "https")
end
```

Now I want to migrate the old images to new sizes, so I updated the model:

```
class PropertyImage < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :picture,
    storage: :s3,
    s3_credentials: CONFIG['s3'],
    s3_protocol: (Rails.env.development? ? "http": "https"),
    styles: {
      thumb: '100x100>',
      large: '633x460>', 
      medium: '301x240>'      
    }
end
```

Now when I try to use the rake provided with Paperclip `rake paperclip:refresh`:

```
RAILS_ENV=development bundle exec rake paperclip:refresh CLASS=PropertyImage
```

And when I check the logs, I'm getting:

```
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  Property Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "properties".* FROM "properties" WHERE ((hidden IS FALSE OR hidden IS NULL) AND sale_or_rental = 'S') AND "properties"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "properties"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 20]]
  SQL (0.6ms)  UPDATE "properties" SET "updated_at" = '2014-10-28 12:33:58.382649' WHERE "properties"."id" = 20
   (1.7ms)  COMMIT
[paperclip] copying /property_images/pictures/000/000/074/original/e9ad004a-09f1-4af3-85c3-772fe3e99acd.gif to local file /var/folders/g8/3v37gc0x16b313mvf7464qtc0000gn/T/2c5a0dd4db750ff6c32b123df2d933ce20141028-28547-j997pz.gif
[AWS S3 200 0.209569 0 retries] get_object(:bucket_name=>"babylon_development",:key=>"property_images/pictures/000/000/074/original/e9ad004a-09f1-4af3-85c3-772fe3e99acd.gif")
```

Two things I noticed here:

1- The rake is trying to save the original images locally `/var/folders/*` (not at s3)

2- The rake is not creating different sizes (thumb, large and medium)

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I had to add `missing_styles` just like:

```
 bundle exec rake paperclip:refresh:missing_styles class=PropertyImage
```